# ActiveRecord requerying depending on order of operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Ruby and Rails so forgive me if my terminology is off a bit.

I am working on optimizing some inherited code and watching the logs I am seeing queries repeat themselves due to lines like this in a .rabl file:

```rb
node(:program) { |user| (!user.programs.first.nil?) ? user.programs.first.name : ''  }
```

`user` and `program` are both active record objects

Moving to the rails console, I can replicate the problem, but I can also get the expected behavior, which is only one query:

```
>u = User.find(1234)
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE [...]
> (!u.programs.first.nil?) ? u.programs.first.name : ''
 Program Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `programs`.* FROM `programs` [...]
 Program Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `programs`.* FROM `programs` [...]
=> "Output"
```

Note that repeating the ternary statement in the console will *always* give me 2 queries.

I can get the expected behavior like so:

```
> newu = User.find(12345)
  User Load (3.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE [...]
> newu.programs
  Program Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `programs`.* FROM `programs` [...]
> (!newu.programs.first.nil?) ? newu.programs.first.name : ''
=> "Output"
```

Repeating the ternary statement now won't requery at all.

So the question is: why does calling `newu.programs` change the behavior? Shouldn't calling `u.programs.first.nil?` also act to load all the program records in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an association, `first` is not sugar for `[0]`.

If the association is loaded, then it just returns the first element of the array. If it is not loaded, it makes a database query to load just that one element. It can't stick that in the association cache (at least not without being smarter), so the next query to `first` does the query again (this will use the query cache if turned on)

What Rails is assuming is that if the association is big, and you are only using one element of it then it would be silly to load the whole thing. This can be a little annoying when this isn't the case and you are just using the one item, but you're using it repeatedly.

To avoid this you can either assign the item to  a local variable so that you do genuinely only call `first` once, or do

```
newu.programs[0]
```

which will load the whole association (once only) and return the first element.

Rails does the same thing with `include?`. Instead of loading the whole collection, it will run a query that tests whether a specific item is in the collection (unless the collection is loaded)

Comment: Ah got it now. Pretty slick. Thanks!